# I doubt Car AC problem in my Volkswagen Polo

Tags: vw, ac, polo

I noticed a gas being released from one of the AC vents(middle one) last week from my Volkswagen Polo (Diesel). It happened twice and lasted around 2 3 seconds. I have never faced any problem with the AC. Is it something I should be concerned of.

Can somebody advice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sounds like a fuel leak and it's in your engine bay so not something to mess around with. You could end up with a fire. Start the engine and start the AC too, but be careful that you don't inhale any gas in the inside of your car. Take any plastic shrouds off the engine and look at the fuel rail, injectors and fuel line for any leaking fuel. If you find it, stop the engine immeadiatly and try to fix the problem with tape or change the rail(s).

Comment: It doesn't sound like a fuel leak at all.  That would have a very distinctive smell.  Every air conditioned car I have ever owned will blow condensation from the vents when the air is humid.

Comment: How on earth could fuel get into the AC system?

Answer (score 5):

This is more than likely just physics in action. If this happened right after you started the A/C and the inside of the car is rather humid, the cold air from the A/C will condense the moisture in the air as it exits the vents. It only happens for a few seconds until the moisture in the air is below the point where it will condense and the temperature inside the vehicle has come down some. **This is completely natural/normal**. I've seen it in my own vehicles many times, especially when I lived in the swamps of Georgia.

Comment: I've spent a whole lot of time analyzing air conditioning (A/C) issues and this is spot on.